# javascript include_once- javascript php calling same file duplicating content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to load a php script that shows content based on screen resolution. The script works great, but the url that ajax calls is also called later in the script-- it holds all of the processing information. So, the result is all content is loaded via jquery and then duplicated with php. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'functions/maxresults.php',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {h: screen.height, w: screen.width}
      }).done(function ( data ) {
          alert("I am working!");
         document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

***And further down***

```
<?php
include_once("functions/maxresults.php");   
?>
```

---

```
<?php
require_once("databasefunctions.php");
?>

<div id="container">
<div id="movieinfo"> 
<?php include("sidebar.php");?>
<?php
// get the function
include_once ('function.php');
if($_GET['page'])
$page = $_GET['page'];
else
$page = 0; 
$maxresults = -1;
if(($_GET['w']) && ($_GET['h'])) {
  $w = $_GET['w'];
  $h = $_GET['h'];
}
  if ($w == 1920) {
    $maxresults = 24;  
  } else if ($w == 1600) {
    $maxresults = 21;  
  } else if ($w == 1440){ 
    $maxresults = 14;
  } else if ($w == 1366) { 
    $maxresults = 21;
  } else if ($w == 1024) {
    $maxresults = 8;
  } else 
    $maxresults = 6;
echo $maxresults;
$currentpage = $page;
$page = $page*$maxresults;
$numpages = QuickQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM movies WHERE visible=1");
$numpages = mysql_result($numpages, 0);
$numpages = $numpages/$maxresults-1;
$result = GetMoviesByRangeID($page, $maxresults);//Show <maxresults> pages at a time
DisplayResults($result); 
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I cannot remove the php include or the script won't work at all. Would creating an include_once in the jquery work and if so, how do I code it?

Comment: This is the wrong approach (since the good one is simply _not_ including the code twice), but you can have a javascript global variable WAS_INCLUDED=true in the php code you include and then have JavaSript check if that variable is defined and execute the code only if it was not. On the other side you can send a GET parameter from js to php.

Comment: @Benjamin if you have time can you show me an example?

Comment: While I feel like it would be only fair to tell you how you could implement it, I can not give you that method as an answer. My honest-to-heart answer is that you need to re-think your design. there is no way this sort of scenario should happen in a well-thought web design. Why are you facing that issue? Why is the same JavaScript code is included twice? Why is it not in a separate .js file? Is your templating well thought out?

Comment: @Ben I am not a programmer- the programmer that developed my website did not know how to implement certain features. I have taught myself design over the last year to fix certain things myself, but am new to the programming side. I am trying to work with what I have.

Comment: Do you know of any good examples of how to GET a parameter from js to php?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a preprocessor. So, it doesn't matter that you are including it 'later' in the file. Your include_once will be processed and output before the JavaScript is executed.

I looks like the problem is that your include_once script is also outputting the container div. So, when you remove that line it breaks the javascript. Try this instead:

1. Remove the container div from you maxresults.php file.
2. Replace the `<?php include_once('functions/maxresults.php);>` with an empty div with an id of container: `<div id="container"></div>`

Your JavaScript should work now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
     url: 'functions/maxresults.php',
     type: 'GET',
     data: {h: screen.height, w: screen.width}
  }).done(function(resp) {
      alert("I am working!");
      $("#container").html(resp);
    });
});
</script>
```

**And further down**

```
<div =id="container"></div>
```

**maxresults.php**

```
<?php
require_once("databasefunctions.php");
?>

<div id="movieinfo"> 
<?php include("sidebar.php");?>
<?php
// get the function
include_once ('function.php');
if($_GET['page'])
$page = $_GET['page'];
else
$page = 0; 
$maxresults = -1;
if(($_GET['w']) && ($_GET['h'])) {
  $w = $_GET['w'];
  $h = $_GET['h'];
}
  if ($w == 1920) {
    $maxresults = 24;  
  } else if ($w == 1600) {
    $maxresults = 21;  
  } else if ($w == 1440){ 
    $maxresults = 14;
  } else if ($w == 1366) { 
    $maxresults = 21;
  } else if ($w == 1024) {
    $maxresults = 8;
  } else 
    $maxresults = 6;
echo $maxresults;
$currentpage = $page;
$page = $page*$maxresults;
$numpages = QuickQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM movies WHERE visible=1");
$numpages = mysql_result($numpages, 0);
$numpages = $numpages/$maxresults-1;
$result = GetMoviesByRangeID($page, $maxresults);//Show <maxresults> pages at a time
DisplayResults($result); 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: the correct dimensions are being outputted- the issue is that all of the content in "container" is being duplicated; shown first by the php (as you clarified) and second by the javascript.

Comment: what exactly does maxresults output? is it creating the container element?

Comment: yes, maxresults is creating the container element and all of the divs/content inside

Comment: Why don't you just empty the container before you add content to it? There would be no duplications this way. But as someone else said, this is done totally wrong. You're hacking a hacked code. Bad. You should instead rethink it.

Comment: @mark thanks, but no content is shown now. The php needs to include maxresults.php, but maybe the ajax can call the container instead of the php?

Comment: In other words, instead of ajax calling a url can it call a div?

Comment: @JJM no. An ajax request is just like if you went to that url with your browser and saved the output into a varible. In the example above the url is http://yoursite.com/functions/maxresults.php, and the variable that output is stored in is 'resp'. We then use $("#container").html(resp) or document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=resp to inject the contents of our variable into the container div. It might be easier to help you if you posted more of your code (like the contents of maxresults.php)

Comment: @mark I see, thanks for explaining. I added maxresults.php above

Comment: BTW when you stated replace <?php include_once you meant with <?php include("<div id='container'></div>"); correct?

Comment: @JJM No. I mean just <div id='container'></div>. You can't include a div via php include - you just add it directly to the page. If you add it to the main page, and delete the corresponding div from your maxresults.php it should work. See my re-edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks- I followed all of the steps you outlined, but still does not work; returns an empty page.